# How do I overwrite the value of a specific child under a key in Firebase using onClick?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to get this to work for over a week now, but I keep running into the same issue. I'm trying to be able to update specifically the child `pickup` value with a on click listener, that is in my recyclerview.

I know I need to query the key from Firebase and that's the part I don't know how to do. Then set the value to the text that I will have set in the `.setValue()`

Here is my database tree:

```
           Chat
  -KgR30muFg-X6xmrqaXA
  address: "123 ST"
  confirm: ""
  description: "Destin: Customer Name  :Jhon"
  phone: "8678876678"
  pickup: ""
  title: "oliver2jason@gmail.com  02:54:44"

  -KgR34XayCVHu2Lveg62
  address: "125 ST"
  confirm: ""
  description: "Miramar: Customer Name  :Nathan "
  phone: "929292929"
  pickup: ""
  title: "oliver2jason@gmail.com  02:55:19"
```

here is my code

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference myref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder>(
            Blog.class,
            R.layout.individual_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            myref
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            viewHolder.setAddress(model.getAddress());
            viewHolder.setPhone(model.getPhone());
            viewHolder.setPickup(model.getPickup());
            viewHolder.setConfirm(model.getConfirm());

        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
}
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    TextView textView_title;
    TextView textView_decription;
    TextView textView_address;
    TextView textView_phone;
    TextView textView_pickup;
    TextView textView_confirm;
    Button bconfirm;
    Button bpickup;



    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
        textView_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView_decription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        textView_address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(address);
        textView_phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(phone);
        textView_pickup = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(pickup);
        textView_confirm = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        bconfirm = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bcomfirm);
        bpickup = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bpickup);



    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        textView_title.setText(title+"");
    }
    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        textView_decription.setText(description);
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        textView_address.setText(address);
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        textView_phone.setText(phone);
    }
    public void setPickup(String pickup) {
        textView_pickup.setText(pickup);
    }
    public void setConfirm(String confirm) {
        textView_confirm.setText(confirm);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get the key of the record that you will be updating then code the onClick method for the button that will update the pickup value:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder>(
            Blog.class,
            R.layout.individual_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            myref){
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            viewHolder.setAddress(model.getAddress());
            viewHolder.setPhone(model.getPhone());
            viewHolder.setPickup(model.getPickup());
            viewHolder.setConfirm(model.getConfirm());
            //Get Record Key
            final String key = this.getRef(position).getKey();

            //Update the Record
            viewHolder.bpickup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myref.child(key).child("pickup").setValue("yourValue");
                }
            };
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: I keep getting the error " the variable recyclerAdapter might not have been initialized

Comment: But you had it initialized through here `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.....`

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I even reset android studio because it doesn't seem right

Comment: I'm not sure why it is giving this error.. any ideas?

Comment: Try changing this `final String key = recyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();` to `final String key = this.getRef(position).getKey();`

Comment: Glad I could help! Thank me accepting the answer and upvoting it. (y)